# Sending and receiving ffmpeg video stream through USB to TTL converter

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming

I need to transfer video signal through USB to TTL converter from one VM and receive it on other USB to TTL converter then display the received stream on second VM (the bitrate on converters are enough to stream my videos).

I can stream or play the "ffmpeg'ed" video on host VM fine, the problems start in receiving end.

I stream the video using:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -f matroska - > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

On receiving end, I tried playing:

```
ffmpeg -I /dev/ttyUSB0 -f mpegts – | ffplay –
```

or similar combinations like

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | ffplay -
```

And saving to file:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 900k -vcodec copy -r 60 -y ReceivedVideo.mp4
```

All of which has returned me with errors in the neighborhood of:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Or:

```
[h264 @ 0x0558b6e462300] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x0558b6e462300] no frame!
[NULL @ 0x0558b6e466900] UNABLE TO FIND CODEC PARAMETERS FOR STREAM 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
```

I'm new to Linux OS and ffmpeg too, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Some technical info:

- **host VM**: Debian OS on WSL12
- **receiving VM**: Debian OS on VirtualBox
- **USB to TTL**: Prolific Pl2303, baudrate 4Mbits the `/dev/ttyUSB0` has `chmod -R 777` permissions

Comment: Your problem may be that the receiving end stops reading the data while the sending end keeps writing. When the receive buffer is full, data gets lost. You can check that the sending `ffmpeg` keeps running even if nothing is running on the receiving end. You should consider enabling flow control by running `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 crtscts` on both ends.